# $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; not returning full query string

Tags: php

Let's say the current URL is www.example.com/example.php?var=test#1

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

should return

> var=test#1

but it just returns

> test

It happens every time a "#" symbol is inserted in the URL.

How can i fix it ? I really need to get the current query string but i CAN'T use $_GET (please don't ask why it would be really too long to explain).
I also have no control over the URL and i can't control the url string or encode it before it reach my server.

Edit: same problem with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Comment: Everything after the `#` pound symbol is the fragment identifier, and always remains client-side. It's never part of the HTTP request path.

Comment: It should return `var=test`. The part after (and including the `#`) is called the hash and it is not sent to the server. So you will never be able to access it from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Comment: I'm not seeing that behaviour here.. Are there any server redirects going on?

Comment: I really need to get the exact query string. I have no control over it and it can contain any characters. If i use $_GET then characters like "? , & , +" will break the result and if i use $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] then symbols like "#" or "|" will also create a bug...... So there is no solution for me ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do actually need to know what the hash is, you will have to use the `document.location.hash` JavaScript property, which contains the contents of the hash....other than that, theres no way to get the hash with php as it is not passed to the sever

Comment: +1. Not sure who down voted this, but you're right. Hashes are client-side only.

Comment: It is not an hash, just an URL with a # ... I need to send the "hash" value to PHP

Comment: It is a hash, thats what # is.  And you cant send it to PHP....anything after # doesn't make it to the server....I already said that

Answer (score 0):

The `#` symbol in a URL represents a link to a named anchor, and isn't part of a query string. To be reliably passed as part of your query data it should be encoded to %23.

Comment: Even if i encode it to %23, $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] still won't read the URL past the %23